# How to get logged in user youtube details using youtube data api v3

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

**how to get logged in user youtube details in react**

had tried using javascript but is there any ways to get ?

i want get youtube details of logged in user , like number of videos and subscribers in react.

Answer (score 1):

The YouTube data api is channel based not user based. There for any information you get back about the currently logged in Channel is not going to be user related.

Request the profile scope and then go though the Google People api.